# Connection timed out while sending email from Roundcube Webmail v1.4.11 ( iRedMail )

Tags: google-cloud-platform, smtp, email-client, iredmail

I am trying to setup a email server on Google clou for which I have used [iRedMail](https://www.iredmail.org/). I have followed [this](https://docs.iredmail.org/install.iredmail.on.debian.ubuntu.html) link to setup. There was no error in logs while sending email to this email server but when I try to send from the UI to my email ID it is giving me following error in logs. ( /var/log/mail.log ).

```
Dec  8 10:19:36 comm postfix/smtp[4142]: connect to mail.tinydef.com[157.230.67.25]:25: Connection timed out
Dec  8 10:19:36 comm postfix/smtp[4142]: 4J8CnP4ND5z3ygl: to=<jamir46881@tinydef.com>, relay=none, delay=31, delays=0.02/0.03/31/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.tinydef.com[157.230.67.25]:25: Connection timed out)
```

I am aware that port 25 is blocked on GCP. Just trying to figure a way out from this situation. Is there any configuration that can be tweaked to change port 25 to some other port ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send mail to external IP addresses on port 25 from instances in Google Cloud. There is no appeal process to change this policy.

[Sending email from an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail)

To function as a mail server requires communication between servers on port 25. Mail relays can use any port the mail server supports except for port 25.

iRedMail can function as a traditional mail server, which requires port 25, and as a mail relay to forward mail to a mail server.

[Setup relayhost](https://docs.iredmail.org/relayhost.html)

Your solution is to configure iRedMail as a relay host forwarding mail on port 465 or 587 to a mail service such as Gmail, Office 365, SendGrid, etc. The email service will deliver your email.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @John . I am not aware how iRedMail can forward and then we can use mail service. The problem statement I am trying to solve is to replace current gmail smtp ( limit 2k email / day ) to have ability to send more email to customers. If you could guide in this direction with some open source options that would really help. Thanks a alot.